# Installed SW on EBS or Instance Store?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ebs

I have launched an `ec2` RHEL instance and have attached `EBS` volume to it.

How do I know when I access data from `/tmp` or `/opt` or any other directory, whether the data is *accessed* from `Instance Store` or `EBS`?

Comment: What type of EC2 instance did you launch, and what do you see when you type `df -kh` at the command line?

Comment: Does the instance type make a difference? I am using t2.medium. I do not see any of the block devices listed on the console to appear as o/p of the command..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `t2.medium` instance type (mentioned in comments) does not include instance store volumes. You can review all instance types with instance store volumes [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#instance-store-volumes). In addition when launching instances with instance store volumes these aren't your root volume and are just available storage you can mount as an additional disk on the instance. For example if you launch a [M5d.large](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/m5/) instance, by default your instance store NVMe drive is available at `/dev/nvme1n1` in linux, but is not used at launch time. You can format and use the instance store volume as you please, after launch.